# PyQt5 QTableWidgetItem как копировать содержимое ячейки но нельзя было чтобы изменять

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

нужно чтобы в таблице можно было скопировать содержимое ячейки, чтобы потом ввести например в строку поиска, но при этом нельзя изменить содержимое. перепробовал наверно все флаги ничего из этого не выходит.
item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable)

```
item_key = self.table.findItems(key, Qt.MatchFlag(0))[0]
item = QTableWidgetItem(str(val))
item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
self.table.setItem(item_key.row(), col, item)
```

я просто заполняю таблицу item и потом когда все вывожу мне надо чтобы можно было из ячейки скопировать содержимое, но нельзя было редактировать

Comment: опубликуйте пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: вы опубликовали все чем можете поделиться ?

Comment: Зачем вы удалили последний ваш вопрос, вам все понятно?

Comment: я его упростил и опубликовал в более понятном виде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129404/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-python-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85