# наследование Python видимость переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование, множественное-наследование

```
class A:
    def ptr(self):
        self.t = 5

class B:
    def ptr2(self):
        self.y = 99
    def sum(self):
        print(self.t + self.y)
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ptr()
        self.ptr2()

ups = C()
ups.sum()
```

С наследует A и B, то есть у С есть атрибуты этих классов(ptr,ptr2,sum), к ним могу в любой момент обратиться. в конструкторе вызываю эти методы , в пространство имен добавляются t и y, но когда вызываю Sum почему это работает, пространство имен у ups t и y, а у B нету t.

Comment: t и y атрибуты объекта класса С, и функцию он наследовал. Кто что  вы предполагаете должен не увидеть?

Comment: но если создать ptr = В() и ptr.sum() будет ошибка

Comment: конечно, не все же аргументы есть. а вот если class b(A); ptr = В(); и дать значения атрибутам, то сумма получится. Init  в C собственно и создает t и y

Comment: интересно , а в С++ будет такой код работать, по такому же принципу?

Comment: наследование в принципе везде работает похоже, но множественное может быть реализовано немного по разному. Именно про C++ точно не знаю

Comment: там точно таким способом не прокатит, он будет требовать переменную, только что попробовал.

Comment: как я понимаю, там вообще невозможно из функции создать атрибут класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам попробую ответить на ваш предыдущий вопрос, который вы зачем-то удалили и опубликовали новый вопрос, который аналог предыдущего https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129347

Когда вы наследуетесь от `Left_Bar` - `self.leftlist` 
становится атрибутом  класса `Manager` и доступен во всех методах этого класса `Manager`.

Когда вы наследуетесь от `Widget2` - методы `stack2UI` и `push_me` становятся 
также объектами класса `Manager` и в них доступны все атрибуты класса `Manager`, 
в том числе и `self.leftlist`.

То что вы написали с множественным наследованием - эквивалентно тому,
что я написал ниже:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QWidget, QStackedWidget,QHBoxLayout,QApplication, \
    QListWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


#class Manager(QWidget, Left_Bar, Widget2):                      # ---
class Manager(QWidget):                                          # +++
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  
        self.leftlist = QListWidget()
        self.leftlist.insertItem(0, 'Редактор')
        self.leftlist.insertItem(1, 'future')

#        self.stack2UI()                                          # ---
        self.stack2 = QWidget()
        self.button = QPushButton('push me')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.push_me)
        self.button.setToolTip("don't push")
        self.stack2.setLayout(self.layout)        
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.Stack = QStackedWidget(self)

        self.Stack.addWidget(self.stack2)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)        # расположение макета
        hbox.addWidget(self.leftlist)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Stack)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('manager')
        self.show()

    def display(self, i):
        self.Stack.setCurrentIndex(i)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def push_me(self):
        self.button.hide()
        self.leftlist.hide()                                # почему он видит leftlist
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(hbox)        
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Manager()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]